# Writing a string value into CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a large data set that has Sentence and their emotion state in the second column. I have developed code to read them as numpy array. Then what I need is, if a sentence's emotion is neutral, then return as true and if not, return false. Each result that return by the if else condition should write in a CSV file. But here it will write the result only one time in the CSV file instead of write all result that return by the each iteration of for loop. Following is the code I have so far.

```
import csv
import numpy as np

with open('Book1.csv', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

for row in reader:
    text=(row['text'])
    emotion=(row['emotion'])
    my_list=(text, emotion)
    my_array = np.asarray(my_list)

    make_array = (text, "neutral")
    num_array = np.asarray(make_array)

    if np.array_equal(my_array,num_array):

        with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['result']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({'result': 'True'})

    else:

        with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['result']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({'result': 'False'})`
```

I might be wrong in somewhere. Somebody please help me.

Comment: `open('test.csv', 'w')` overwrites the file every time it is called. You will need to either open in in append mode `open('test.csv', 'a')`, or better still, open it only once before the loop. Also, the code under `with open('Book1.csv', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:` should be indented one level.

Comment: oh wow, for every line in book1.csv , you are opening,writing and closing test.csv. Cant you just make a dictionary of required records first and perform write at last..?

Comment: Any way finally I want to count True and False value. If there is another way rather than that I following. Please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open the file for *append* rather than *writing*, if I understand the problem correctly.

```
with open('test.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['result']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'result': 'True'})
```

Also, you are repeating code in the if/else conditional blocks ; you should create a variable `result_dict` which equals {'result': 'True'} or {'result': 'False'} and then write that outside of the if/else blocks so you don't have to open the file in the conditional blocks. Let me know if this isn't clear.

Comment: I tried for your code. The column name also write repeatly. How can I fix it?

Comment: Yes Please. I'm not clear what you said. Let me know how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by column name here?

Comment: I mean fieldnames = ['result']

Comment: Use a counter in the for loop, to see if you are at 0 or >0. If greater than 0, then no need to write header, otherwise write header.